# SQL Server : how to get latest date and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the latest `CreationTime` and `Value` for each rows but I am getting multiple rows for each condition. Can somebody please help with this?

This is my code and results:

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.PatientAccountID
       ,e.FindingAbbr
       ,e.Value
       ,e.CreationTime
FROM 
    PatientVisit a with (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    Assessment d with (nolock) ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
INNER JOIN 
    Observation e with (nolock) ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
WHERE
    a.PatientAccountID = '11'

     AND a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
     AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
     AND e.Value != ''

    AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_IV1 Site', 'A_IV2 Site', 'A_IV3 Site', 'A_IV4 Site')

     AND EXISTS
    (SELECT DISTINCT Max(e.CreationTime)
     FROM Observation e with (nolock))
     Order by a.PatientAccountID
```

I am getting below Results:

```
        PatientAccountID    FindingAbbr Value   CreationTime
11  A_IV1 Site  L Forearm            11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV1 Site  L Forearm            11/10/2014 1:40
11  A_IV1 Site  L Forearm            11/9/2014 18:18
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm            10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm            10/31/2014 10:26
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm            10/30/2014 22:31
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm            10/29/2014 23:10
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm            10/29/2014 8:31
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/10/2014 1:40
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/9/2014 18:18
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/9/2014 18:17
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/9/2014 11:12
11  A_IV2 Site  R Antecubital   10/31/2014 10:26
11  A_IV2 Site  R Antecubital   10/30/2014 22:31
11  A_IV2 Site  R Antecubital   10/29/2014 23:10
11  A_IV2 Site  R Antecubital   10/29/2014 8:31
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/10/2014 1:40
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/9/2014 18:18
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/9/2014 18:17
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/9/2014 11:12
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/8/2014 20:57
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/8/2014 7:40
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm            11/8/2014 4:24
11  A_IV1 Site  R Forearm            10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV1 Site  R Forearm            10/31/2014 10:26
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/31/2014 10:26
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/30/2014 22:31
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/29/2014 23:10
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/29/2014 8:31
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/28/2014 23:52
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/28/2014 13:41
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/28/2014 9:26
```

And I want my results like this:

```
PatientAccountID   FindingAbbr   Value                CreationTime
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    11             A_IV1 Site      L Forearm          11/10/2014 9:47
    11             A_IV2 Site      R Antecubital      10/31/2014 10:26
    11             A_IV3 Site      R Forearm          11/10/2014 9:47
    11             A_IV4 Site      R Antecubital      11/10/2014 9:47
```

Hello All:
Thank you all for you help. I tried all input from you guys and it did eliminated most of the duplicate rows. But now I am getting 2 rows for each FindingAbbr and I understand it is because of the unique values associated with it but is there any way I can get only one Row for each FindingAbbr based on latest CreationTime. Below is the results I am getting now.
Thank you.

```
PatientAccountID    FindingAbbr Value   CreationTime
11  A_IV1 Site  L Forearm   11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV1 Site  R Forearm   10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV2 Site  R Forearm   11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV2 Site  R Antecubital   10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV3 Site  R Forearm   11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV3 Site  R Upper Arm 10/31/2014 20:57
11  A_IV4 Site  R Antecubital   11/10/2014 9:47
11  A_IV4 Site  L Forearm   10/31/2014 20:57
```

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT PatientAccountID, FindingAbbr, Value, CreationTime
FROM (SELECT a.PatientAccountID, e.FindingAbbr, e.Value, e.CreationTime,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.FindingAbbr ORDER BY e.CreationTime) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.Value) as cnt
      FROM PatientVisit a with (nolock) INNER JOIN
           Assessment d with (nolock)
           ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid INNER JOIN
           Observation e with (nolock)
           ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
      WHERE a.PatientAccountID = '11' AND
            a.VisitTypeCode='IP' AND
            a.VisitEndDateTime is null AND
            e.Value <> '' AND
            e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_IV1 Site', 'A_IV2 Site', 'A_IV3 Site', 'A_IV4 Site')
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

Comment: hi I was able to avoid most of the rows but I am still getting some duplicates and not sure why is that. Below is the results I get from above query.

Comment: You seem to want one row per `FindingAbbr` rather than `Value`, so I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. what I am trying to do is I need to get the results for each FindingAbbr displyed only once the latest value and the latest time. But with above query I am only getting the latest time and latest value for only FindingAbbr "A_IV1 Site". I am getting 2 rows for others with differnt dates.

Comment: @AlicaShah . . . I thought you wanted the first as well as the last values.  You can just change the `where` clause to `seqnum = cnt` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `GROUP BY` on the FindingAbbr, Value, and PatientID then putting a `MAX()` on your CreationTime so it knows to select the latest entry

```
SELECT    a.PatientAccountID ,e.FindingAbbr,
          e.Value, max(e.CreationTime) as CreationTime
FROM      dbo.vw_ORE_PatientVisitInfo a with (nolock)
JOIN      dbo.hAssessment d with (nolock) ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
JOIN      dbo.HObservation e with (nolock) ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
WHERE     a.PatientAccountID= '11'
          AND a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
          AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
          AND e.Value <> ''
          AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_IV1 Site', 'A_IV2 Site', 'A_IV3 Site', 'A_IV4 Site')
          AND EXISTS
         (SELECT DISTINCT Max(e.CreationTime)
         FROM dbo.HObservation e with (nolock))
         Order by a.PatientAccountID)
GROUP BY    e.FindingAbbr, e.PatientAccountID, e.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to do something like this.  You can work out the details.

```
select yourfields
from table1
join (
select somefield, max(DateTimeField) maxdt
from table1 
group by somefield
where whatever) temp  on table1.somefield = temp.somefield
and DateTimeField = maxdt
where whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants this:

```
SELECT    e.PatientAccountID ,e.FindingAbbr,
          e.Value, max(e.CreationTime) as CreationTime
FROM      dbo.vw_ORE_PatientVisitInfo a with (nolock)
JOIN      dbo.hAssessment d with (nolock) ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
JOIN      dbo.HObservation e with (nolock) ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
WHERE     a.PatientAccountID= '11'
          AND a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
          AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
          AND e.Value != ''
          AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_IV1 Site', 'A_IV2 Site', 'A_IV3 Site', 'A_IV4 Site')
          AND EXISTS
         (SELECT DISTINCT Max(e.CreationTime)
         FROM dbo.HObservation e with (nolock))
         Order by a.PatientAccountID)
GROUP BY    e.FindingAbbr, e.PatientAccountID, e.Value
```

Comment: Although, given all that 'no lock' in the code, you would likely want to take the results an wrap it with a select distinct <fieldList> from () x; or put it into a temp table and do the equivlant.

Comment: Might want to do a `<>` instead of `!=`.

Comment: It did eliminated most of the rows but i am getting 2 rows for each FindingAbbr and its is because of unique Values associsted with it. but is there any way i can just display only one rows based on latest time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select PatientAccountID,FindingAbbr,Value,LatestCreationTime from
(SELECT
   a.PatientAccountID
   ,e.FindingAbbr
   ,e.Value
   ,max(e.CreationTime) as LatestCreationTime


FROM PatientVisit a with (nolock)
INNER JOIN Assessment d with (nolock)
ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
INNER JOIN Observation e with (nolock)
ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
WHERE
a.PatientAccountID= '11'

 AND a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
 AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
 AND e.Value != ''

AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_IV1 Site', 'A_IV2 Site', 'A_IV3 Site', 'A_IV4 Site')
 Group BY a.PatientAccountID
   ,e.FindingAbbr) as query
Order by a.PatientAccountID
```